# GPIO directory missing in /sys/class

Tags: linux-device-driver

I have installed ubuntu 11.04 in pandaboard REV B3. I tried for gpio directory in /sys/class but  gpio folder is not there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sysfs interface (/sys/class/gpio/...) is optional. Make sure your kernel configuration has the CONFIG_GPIO_SYSFS option enabled and rebuild.